# Why do we need a separate <shared_mutex> header file?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, header-files, readwritelock

Can we just put shared_mutex under the same  header file, rather than a separate <shared_mutex> header file?

When I use `shared_mutex`, I thought I only need to `#include <mutex>`. It turns out that I need to `#include <shared_mutex>` as well.

Is it more convenient to put all related mutexes into one header file `<mutex>`?

Comment: Why not all the standard library is contained within a single header? Because you want to include only what you use, and not much more

Comment: With std modules you'll get your wish with `import std;`. In the meantime, std headers are huge and I wish they were split up further than they are!

Comment: I'm confused about what perspective you're taking on this.  Are you planning on proposing a change to the standards committee?  Because you can make your _own_ header files that do whatever you want.

Comment: This would slow down the build times of all programs that need mutexes but not shared mutexes.

Comment: `all_mutex.h`: `#pragma once \ #include <mutex> \ #include <shared_mutex>`

Comment: Correct term is **header**; because they normally appear at the top of the code .

Comment: If the build times are so important, why haven't the standard committee separated recursive_mutex into <recursive_mutex> header file?

Comment: Why anything? Unless you get a member of the committee here you're unlikely to get an authoritative answer.

Comment: There are some good comments and answers here.  I just wanted to add that [`<shared_mutex>` contains more than `shared_mutex`](http://eel.is/c++draft/shared.mutex.syn).  It contains a collection of closely related types and functions.

Comment: Thanks @HowardHinnant for responding to my mail. It’s good to have you here. What exactly was the reason for separating `shared_mutex` from other mutual exclusion related code in the `mutex` header? Why did you write it in a different header? Did the standard committee raise this during approval? Is there a policy guiding header files and what should be their contents to be grouped as one unit? Please forgive me for asking these many questions :)

Comment: My rationale for proposing the separate header was that it added a lot of code for a use case that is (or should be) much less common than that for <mutex>.  So compile-time takes a hit for a bunch of users who don't benefit from it.  And soon that won't matter with the std module.  This is a restatement of comments made above.  Additionally my original proposal put even more code in <shared_mutex>: `upgrade_mutex` and `upgrade_lock`.  The anticipated uses of these were even rarer.  But a judgement was made that they did not warrant a separate header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointing out the premise of this question would be helpful to future academia.

If we take a closer look at the standard library, we see a certain pattern; a simple example is a look at the [`memory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) header which contains a few standard classes for easy [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) along with many functions and helper classes. This is also the case with the [`algorithm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header.

The OP asks:

> Can we just put `[std::]shared_mutex` under same header file [`mutex`], rather than separate `shared_mutex` header file?

When [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) proposed [Shared locking in C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3568.html), in his [Proposed Wording](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3568.html#Wording), he writes it exactly like this:

> Header <shared_mutex> synopsis

From the very beginning, he meant it to be in a separate header and made it so. Somehow this got into the standard exactly like this.

Can we correct this [if we imply there is a mistake to begin with]? Theoretically **yes**. Practically, it is complicated. C++ has always promised to be a stable language. [Stroustrup has always reiterated on this throughout his over 50 years of work on this language](https://www.stroustrup.com/). Trying to change this subtle diversion in the standard library is unnecessary and arguably harmless. Some users of the standard library will even see this as an advantage rather than an inconvenience.

**Edit:** Howard has given a clarification on this subject. I will quote this verbatim:

> My rationale for proposing the separate header was that it added a lot of code for a use case that is (or should be) much less common than that for `mutex`. So compile-time takes a hit for a bunch of users who don't benefit from it. And soon that won't matter with the std module. This is a restatement of comments made above. Additionally my original proposal put even more code in `shared_mutex`: `upgrade_mutex` and `upgrade_lock`. The anticipated uses of these were even rarer. But a judgement was made that they did not warrant a separate header.

Comment: Thank you! This background is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This is because engineers think in quite opposite way:

*When I use a mutex, I don't have to know anything about anything else, like shared_mutex.*

And here is the overall great advice as a rule of thumb:

> "Perfection is achieved not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away" (Antoine de Saint-Exupéry)

On the question about the counterexample - `recursive_mutex`.

The `shared_mutex` implementation is about 300+ lines of code with some API to learn. Compilation of this code is expensive and excessive in case you don't need it. The `recursive_mutex` is 10 lines of code while `recursive_mutex` is still a `_Mutex_base` and a "sibling" of `mutex`. They are "mutexes".

So it is quite reasonable to have them together. Otherwise, it goes to such huge fragmentation that you will payback for putting this together too much.

At the same time `shared_mutex` doesn't not implement `_Mutex_base` and doesn't inherit from it, so this is a "separate" thing.

Of course, this is a design decision to have the balance. Note that high level rules always provide a range instead of a specific precise answer so that one can apply it for wide variety of current circumstances and foresight. I explained the reason providing generic answer, which is the base for [YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) (as *Swift - Friday Pie* noted), which is the base for *Howard Hinnant*'s particular decision. It is your decision which generalization level of the answer to accept, all works.

So far it is the engineer's work to strive for balance; in case you decouple too much, you will have to payback for putting things together.

Comment: If so, then why is the recursive_mutex not separated into <recursive_mutex>?

Comment: *"Perfection is achieved not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away" (Antoine de Saint-Exupéry)* This is a weak argument and it doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: @DengzhiZhang, because of complexity. The `shared_mutex` implementation is about 300+ lines of code with some API to learn. Compilation of this code is expensive and excessive in case you don't need it. The `recursive_mutex` is 10 lines of code while `recursive_mutex` is still a `_Mutex_base` and a "sibling" of mutex. So it is quite reasonable to have them together. Otherwise, it goes to such huge fragmentation that you will payback for putting this together too much. Of course, this is a design decision to have the balance.

Comment: @DengzhiZhang, I updated the answer with slightly more information.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon it's YAGNI principle. Which, ironically, was based on that particular quote

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie it was not explicitly stated as a design philosophy for the C++ standard library. Which is why the OP noticed the divergence. I gave an example in my answer. Why wasn’t the YAGNI principle applied to the `memory` header for instance? For every example you give of it’s application in the standard library, I can give 10 of where the principle isn’t applied.

Comment: @DengzhiZhang, this is always a design decision is strive for balance, not for adherence to some corner case law. The key is that any rule or idea give you not a precise answer, but a range and you seek for best solution in this range taking into account current requirements and a bit of foresight. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon not sure what do you mean, memory doesn't contain independant entities where order of declaration wouldn't change behaviour. That's a perfect example where decoupling would be detrimental or would effect implementation. And yes , it's always harmony of YAGNI and god-like entities, of DRY and WET, of backward compatibility and simplicity to use.